# huge div border rendering issue

Tags: css, html, border

I have a really weird case where borders and background image is not rendered past some point in some huge divs. I have included a sample in the following fiddle!
http://jsfiddle.net/hg333/

```
<div class="lane">
<div class="label-container"> <span class="label">3 - 5</span> 
</div>
```

In the rendered example the borders are "clipped". You will see that if you scroll to the right the lines stop at 4th March but the div continues (approx. 12000px) in the rendered context.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: That is because the border is going to the width of the window, while what you are looking for is something wider

Comment: @Andrew Are you sure? If I view the output frame of that fiddle full screen, the borders don't take up the width of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas container is set to 1200px, that's what is causing the problem.

Try:

```
 #canvas-container {
/*   width: 1200px;*/
overflow: visible;
}
```

I tried on fiddle without the width, and it worked. That's why I left it with comment marks "`/* */`"